# Do files lose their UTI when copied to another file system?

Tags: filesystem, uti, ntfs, hfs+

From what I understand, if you create a file on OS X it will have a Uniform Type Identifier. I'm not sure if it's part of the file system or the file itself. If you copy the file to another file system (say NTFS), will it still have the UTI associated with it if you copy it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTIs are stored on the file system itself, so they are not copied with the file if you move it to another file system.

[Where do UTI come from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943819/where-do-uti-come-from)